# TFS 2015U3 build REST api specify reuqired demands

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to use the TFS rest API to trigger various builds. Each build that gets triggered, requires different demands.

E.g. I tried something like:

```
{ 
 "definition": {
     "id": 190
},
"sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
"demands":{"XXXXXXX":""},
```

This build executes fine, although no Agent satisfies the demand. Also various variations didn't work as expected.

In the documentation https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/overview I was not able to find anything regarding demands.

How does the body need to look like, so that the demands work?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting my http traffic with fiddler I finally found out what the body needs to be to send demands:

```
$body = @"
{ 
  "definition": {
  "id": 190
  },
  "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
  "parameters": "{\"configuration\":\"Debug\"}",
  "demands":["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","yyyyyyyyyyy -equals zzzzzzzzzzzzz"],
}
"@
```